# Typescript issue: Argument of type 'HelpGetResponse' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I have a react componenet in type script that is giving me an error and I am not sure how to fix this error:

```
Argument of type 'HelpGetResponse' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.
  Type 'HelpGetResponse' is not assignable to type '(prevState: never[]) => never[]'.
    Type 'HelpGetResponse' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: never[]): never[]'.ts(2345)
```

where i am getting the error:

```
        helpApi.getHelpFiles().then((response) => {
            if (response.status !== 200) return;
            setFiles(response.data);
            checkFileContent();
        });
```

the error appears at the response.data

here is where the helpApi declares the help get response:

stackdto:

```
import { IdDTO } from "./IdDTO";
import { createValidator } from "./validate";

export interface HelpDTO {
    text: string;
    path: string;
    leaf: boolean;
    children: [] | null;
}

export interface HelpGetResponse {
    results: number;
    data: HelpDTO[];
}
```

and other file with the api call

```
import * as qs from "qs";

import { Gateway, getGateway, Response } from "../interfaces";

import { HelpGetResponse } from "./../models/HelpDTO";

export class HelpAPI {
    private readonly gateway: Gateway;

    constructor(gateway?: Gateway) {
        this.gateway = gateway || getGateway();
    }

    getHelpFiles(): Promise<Response<HelpGetResponse>> {
        return this.gateway.get("helpFiles/", {});
    }

    getHelpFileById(path: string): Promise<Response<HelpGetResponse>> {
        return this.gateway.get(`help${path}/`, {});
    }
}

export const helpApi = new HelpAPI();
```

Comment: pretty sure the issue is you need to define the type on `children`. typescript reads `[]` as `never[]`. so change this part `children: [] | null;` to be something more explicit

Comment: so have a case of no [] for children.... would i need to change the null part of [] part. @JohnRuddell

Comment: no... `[]` is the same thing as `never[]` so you need something like `children: SomeType[] | null`

Comment: i tried setting it to any but it did not do anything... `children: any[] | null;` @JohnRuddell

Comment: wherever you define the hook / state item that is of type `never[]` you need to fix that